# wordpress standard post slug

Tags: wordpress, post, slug

i have all my standard posts in wordpress 3.8 on a site called news (www.site.com/news). if i create a new post the url is like www.site.com/postname but i want www.site.com/news/postname just for the standard posts of WP (i have a lot of custom posts too. i can handle their slugs easy with the config). i get the posts manually in my template file with just the ppp argument.

furthermore there is another language so i must be able to provide www.site.com/lang/news/postname too.

thanks for any hints

EDIT: .htaccess

```
   addhandler php53-cgi .php
   php_value upload_tmp_dir "/www/htdocs/xxx/tmp"
   php_value session.save_path "/www/htdocs/xxx/tmp"

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Upload it in your server.
Use in permalinks "**Custom Structure**":  `/%category%/%postname%/`
Also you should have a look here [wpml.org](http://wpml.org/) (features [wpml.org/features](http://wpml.org/features)).

Comment: ty for your reply. unfortunatly this has no effect. Yes i'm using wpml already

Comment: Can you please edit your question by adding your **.htaccess** file?